# loop through an empty array filled by 'push' metod

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I've gotten stuck here. My web page has a paragraph with `id="history"` and I need a function to loop through `myArray` and if `myArray[i]` matches, for example, `10` as shown below then do something. Please don't suggest jQuery as I'll be learning that later.

```
    var myArray = [];

    function myFunction(){
      // do something
      myArray.push(8);
      myArray.push(10);
    }

    function myOtherFunction(){
      document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = myArray;
    }


    function myAnotherFunction(){
      for (var i = 0; i<=myArray.length; i++){
        if (myArray[i] === 10){
          //do something
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your upper bound in the loop is off by one.

Comment: What should be done if the array item is indeed 10?

Comment: The code looks fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me except one that you have a logical error in code. There is index out of bound for array in loop. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apanery/h4aUL) might be helpful to you.

```
var myArray = [];

    function myFunction(){
      // do something
      myArray.push(8);
      myArray.push(10);
    }

    function myOtherFunction(){
      document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = myArray;
    }


    function myAnotherFunction(){
      for (var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        if (myArray[i] == 10){
            myOtherFunction();
          //do something
        }
      }
    }
myFunction();
myAnotherFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm still having a problems. So I uploaded my actual code (stripped a little:) http://jsfiddle.net/3vJH6/1/

Comment: I have checked your code. what are you going to do with this code? What's the problem